# cant get coordmode to work in a very simple script

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote this script so I can mouseclick 4 coordinates in the screen via their own hotkey.

But when opening any windows the koordinates get messed up.

Tried to include the coordmode but it doesnt run at all.

Tried to figure this out but examples i found where way more complex scripts so I didnt understand.

A little advice would be greatly appreciated. ty.

```
*1:: 
Click 325, 333 
return

*2:: 
Click 809, 334
return

*3:: 
Click 318, 699
return

*4::
Click 813, 696
return
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the following at the top of your script

```
CoordMode,Mouse,Relative
```

This will make your (new) mouse coordinates relative to the window, not the screen.

Could you try this in another script?

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent
SetTimer, Check, 300
Check:
MouseGetPos,X,Y
ToolTip,X%X%`,Y%Y%
Return
```

When running it show the mouse coordinates as they are right tehn (based on screen, not window)

Comment: tx for reply. I actually want it to click coordinates relative to the screen not the window. so i included Coordmouse,Mouse, Screen. When i put it 1 time on top of the script it still messes up, klicks all over the place. if i put in front of every single line it doesnt work at all.

Comment: the postet script doesnt run. checked my other scripts, they do run.

Comment: no problem im thankful i found help. yes this script shows me coordinates relative to screen. And when i include CoordMode,Mouse,Relative it shows coordinates relative to window.

Comment: including CoordMode,Mouse,Screen seems to have no effect on my little script

Comment: And your'e sure you didn't mix-up x/y?

Comment: yes. sometimes it works for a little while. clicking the right coordinates. im not sure if its opening windows which causes the errors. but as soon as the first error comes it wont return to normal function. a friend of mine btw testet the script and has the same issue.

Comment: are you using this in a game?

Comment: yes. online poker at fulltilt.eu to be exact. But error happens with or with out software running. Scripts from other authors just dont have this single feature which is the only feature I want.

Comment: I am stunned, this is so simple and I've not had any mouse position issues. A simple click should work. Have you tried asking the question on http://www.autohotkey.com/board/ There is a larger and more focussed community there.

Comment: stunned to. never thought it will take several hours to make this very simple funktion work. thanks for your time mr. Ilbrink. just to make sure you mean this should definately work? CoordMode,Mouse,Screen       
*1:: 


Click 325, 333 

return       

*2:: 


Click 809, 334 return

*3:: 


Click 318, 699 return
*4:: 


Click 813, 696 

return  Will look on the ahkboard. ty for your time

Comment: Yes it should and it does on my machine. Very reliable I might say. See you at the AHK Board.